# Данные из форм не попадают в базу данных

Tags: python, django

Ввожу данные в форму - там пароль, почта, ну вообщем делаю регистрацию и авторизацию. И остановился на том, что данные при вводе просто не попадают в базу. Данные я проверял, открывал db.sqlite3, пролистал от начала до конца и не нашел данных, которые заполнял. Проверял все файлы, они тоже не изменились. Сделал вывод, что они туда просто не попали. Помогите, пожалуйста, и по возможности покажите, как сделать регистрацию и авторизацию.

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {'form': form,
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', context)




def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username == User.objects.filter:
            auth.login()
        return render(request, '/')
    return render('registration/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Registration(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password1= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Registration


class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ['username','email','password', 'password1', 'password2']
```

registred.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
 <h3>Введите Логин</h3> <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}"> <br>
 <h3>Введите Почту</h3> <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}"> <br>
 <h3>Введите Пороль</h3> <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password1 }}"> <br>
  <h3>Повторите пороль</h3><input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password2 }}"> <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

login.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Логин</h3><input type="text" name="username">
        <h3>Пароль </h3> <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Зачем Вы создали модель `Registration`? Почему вы привязываете к ней форму? Весь код никак не связан между собой. Кажется, Вы немного ранее спрашивали про авторизацию и регистрацию, так чем Вам не угодил мой вариант?

Answer (score 0):

В первых, вам не нужна модель. Вы дублируете стандартную модель User из django.contrib.auth.models. 
Во вторых, вам незачем 3 поля в модели для пароля (если же вы не собираетесь собирать и хранить пароли в открытом виде) 
В третьих, вам нужна форма от стандартной модели
В четвертых - [то что вам нужно - первая ссылка гугла](https://ustimov.org/posts/17/)

Пояслнения по моделям - они должны хранить недублирующуюся информацию. В вашем варианте целых 3 поля под пароль, и сомневаюсь что он будет шифроваться. Это прохой вариант, если вы конечно несобираетесь красть пароли пользователей (ай-ай-ай, нехорошо тогда)

Про шаблон формы. Форма должна выводиться целеиком `{{form}}` или же по полям `{{form.username}}` `{{form.password}}` и т.д